# CSS animation is not working?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I want to rotate the object first and make it fall down.
Here is my code. Not sure what the mistake is.

**CSS**

```
body {
}
#hammer
{
    -webkit-animation: hammer 5s linear 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: hammer 5s linear 2s infinite;
    animation: hammer 5s linear 2s infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes myfirst
 {
     0%  {-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);}
    100%  {-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}
@keyframes myfirst 
{
    0%  {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
    100%  {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes myfirst
 {
     0%  {-moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);}
    100%  {-moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<center><img id="hammer" src="hammer.png" alt="hammer" width="100" height="100" /></center>
```

Answer (score 4):

Because you are rotating from 360 to 360 nothing is happening. Try to Rotate from 0 to 360

Answer (score -1):

1. you need to change "hammer" to the real animation's name "myfirst"

   animation: myfirst 0.4s ease
2. add a transition to `#hammer` to see the animation softly

   ```
   #hammer {
       transition: all 0.5s ease
   }
   ```